# Unable to create Stored routine which returns some value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am working in Maria DB. I have stored procedure. Now I need to add some return functionality. For  that purpose, I have created a new function which looks like this -

```
CREATE FUNCTION `insertChild`(`nodeId` INT, `newNodeName` INT)
    RETURNS INT
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    Rollback;

START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM item_tree WHERE item_id = nodeId;

    UPDATE item_tree SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt >= @myRight;
    UPDATE item_tree SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;
    INSERT INTO item_tree(item_name, lft, rgt) VALUES(newNodeName, @myRight , @myRight + 1);

    RETURN (SELECT (COUNT(parent.item_name) - 1) AS depth FROM item_tree AS node,
        item_tree AS parent
    WHERE node.item_id = last_insert_id() AND 
    node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt 
    GROUP BY node.item_name
    ORDER BY node.lft);

COMMIT;

END
```

But, this is not working. It is returning a SQL error(1415)  : Not allowed to return a resultset from a function.

What is the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34898142/5678086

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way it returns. setting the count in a variable and return that. Please check the updated code below

```
CREATE FUNCTION `insertChild`(`nodeId` INT, `newNodeName` INT)
    RETURNS INT
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    Rollback;

START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM item_tree WHERE item_id = nodeId;

    UPDATE item_tree SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt >= @myRight;
    UPDATE item_tree SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;
    INSERT INTO item_tree(item_name, lft, rgt) VALUES(newNodeName, @myRight , @myRight + 1);

    SELECT @myCount := (COUNT(parent.item_name) - 1) AS depth FROM item_tree AS node,
        item_tree AS parent
    WHERE node.item_id = last_insert_id() AND 
    node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt 
    GROUP BY node.item_name
    ORDER BY node.lft;

    RETURN @myCount;

COMMIT;

END
```

Comment: Thanks... but, again this is giving the same error.. :(

Comment: is there any way I can use the above code (except the line with RETURN) in stored Proc and get the value of @ myCount.

Comment: procedure does not return anything as function does